# Track location of friends

Tags: ios, facebook, geolocation, location, friend

I would like to make it possible for the user to track their friends through one of my applications. The application is for a music festival.

I have been thinking of ways to do this:

1. Let the user set a nickname for the device (associated with the UDID) and let users add each other to a "friend list" by their nickname. When the application is running the location of the users would be sent around through push messages. This might be a bit hard to integrate - and I kind of hate working with push notifications.
2. Set up accounts for each user then store the user's most recent location in a database and read them. Again, users will add each other by nicknames. This would be a really easy solution but I am not sure if it is legal to store the location of the user (maybe I could ask them for permission and not have this option enabled by default?)
3. I have seen an application doing this "friend tracking" and doing it by having the user log into Facebook. I did not try this feature and I do not know how they do it with Facebook. Maybe you do?

Any thoughts on these solutions or are there any other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: Which application uses the Facebook API as the tracking method?

Comment: It was a Danish application. It doesn't seem to exist anymore. I'm not sure if they used Facebook as tracking method - all I know is that they wanted you to log into Facebook when using the friend tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen google latitude?
http://nexos.ravex.net.au/apps/xnetViewer/?q=google+latitude

Has api
http://code.google.com/apis/latitude/